# How can I create big matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to create a matrix of Matlab, it's big matrix as below:

```
X = zeros(128,2e7);
```

when I run the command, it gives me an error of

> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Is there a way to avoid that error?

Thank you

Comment: Buying more RAM avoids the error. (Seriously: If the matrix is too large to fit in your RAM, then you can't create that matrix.)

Comment: what's about using sparse matrix,  is it different from my stuation ?

Comment: That array requires about 20GB of ram. More than your have. Do you have to keep all in ram at the same time? Do you nead double precision?

Comment: @Daniel I didn't get what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you need such a large matrix? How will you use it? What is the end goal? Giving more information would help people identify the right approach for you.

Answer (score 3):

If it fits your use case, you could use a [sparse matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

There is also [tall arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html)

Comment: In sparse matrix, is there any difference with X = zeros(128,2e7);  ?? or matrix must be sparse in that case ?

Comment: I think it internally keeps track of non-zero values so if you have lots of zeros and very few actual values, sparce matrices work well. If you have a lot of non-zero values then they are no good. Also have a look at tall arrays

Comment: my matrix is all non-zeros values,  is there any other solution ?

Comment: @Gze so in this case a sparse matrix is perfectly suited. Why would you use something else ?

Comment: @obchardon if the matrix doesn't contain zeros, it means sparse matrix is the suited solution ??  is that what you mean ?

Comment: @Gze: If you matrix is not at least 50% zeros, don't use a sparse matrix.

Comment: There is also tall arrays, did you take a look at those? Do they not work for you either?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
zeros(128,2e7,'single');
```

It can work with you

Comment: MATLAB is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the code

```
X = zeros(128,2e7);
```

An array of this size requires 128*2e7*8 Byte of storage. This is about 20GB. Considering an average PC, you probably don't have 20GB of ram available for MATLAB. The direct answer to your question is, NO you can not use more RAM than your PC has available.

Possible strategies are:

- Do you really need all the elements in RAM at the same time? Maybe you can keep the Matrix on disk and process it piece by piece?
- Do you need double precision? This is the default data type in Matlab. Maybe single or an integer data type would be sufficient. What do you want to store in each element of the matrix?